# Using .Sas7bdat file and merging in R

Tags: r, merge

I am a beginner in R. The data i am using is in .Sas7bdat not in .csv. 
I have read three data sets from sas7bdat as follows.

The codes below:

```
library(sas7bdat)

ds1 <-read.sas7bdat("q:/file name1.sas7bdat")

ds2<-read.sas7bdat("q:/file name2.sas7bdat")

ds3<-read.sas7bdat("q:/file name3.sas7bdat")
```

I need to merge all these three file based on ID. There are uneven number of variables in each data set. I used the following codes,

```
newds <-merge(ds1,ds2,ds3, by="id",all=TRUE)

Error in fix.by(by.x, x) :'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical
```

How could I recover this error and compute mean and Standard deviation after this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two compact methods for passing multiple lists to `merge`: `do.call` and `Reduce`. My attempts with the do.call method failed here (I think) because the third data.frame was being matched to the 'by' argument. Instead, try:

```
newds <-Reduce( function(x,y) merge(x,y, by="id", all=TRUE), 
                list(ds1,ds2,ds3) )
```

If you do not provide the structure of the dataframes, it's not possible to give further coding advice about how to "compute mean and Standard deviation".